# Program to create ecard from photo?

Tags: photos

I have [HP Photo Creations](http://www.hp.com/global/us/en/consumer/digital_photography/free/software/photo-creations.html) which is a program that let us create card/calendar based on our photo

I want to know if there are other similar software on the market ?

Thanks